# Cant pass variable in Javascript function

Tags: javascript

I am building a string and creating a table with it:

```
table += '<td>'+ '<a href="#" onclick="portal_openModalDialog();" >'+ oListItem.get_item('Title') +'</a>'  + '</td>'
```

When I click the link, the function fires.

I need to pass some Javascript variables in the function `VarTest()` so I've written the code:

```
table += '<td>'+ '<a href="#" onclick="portal_openModalDialog('+ VarTest + ');" >'+ oListItem.get_item('Title') +'</a>'  + '</td>'
```

But nothing happens, I've tried all sorts of options but nothing works.

This works (with +) but then nothing gets passed.

```
table += '<td>'+ '<a href="#" onclick="portal_openModalDialog('+')" >'+ oListItem.get_item('Title') +'</a>'  + '</td>'


var VarTest = "my text";
function portal_openModalDialog(Title) {
    alert(Title);
}
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE: (this now works for single argument)

```
table += '<td>'+ '<a href="#" onclick="portal_openModalDialog1(&quot;'+oTitle+'&quot;)" >'+ oListItem.get_item('Title') +'</a>'  + '</td>';
```

but not if I pass 2 arguments:

```
table += '<td>'+ '<a href="#" onclick="portal_openModalDialog1(&quot;'+oTitle,oDescription+'&quot;)" >'+ oListItem.get_item('Title') +'</a>'  + '</td>';
```

The html gets rendered on the screen:

```
<a href="#" onclick="portal_openModalDialog1(&quot;Bank of England</tr><tr><td><img src='../Style Library/Icons/Noticeboard_News.png' /></td><td><a href="#" onclick="portal_openModalDialog1(&quot;Investor centre - Reed Elsevier</tr><tr><td><img src='../Style Library/Icons/Noticeboard_News.png' /></td><td><a href="#" onclick="portal_openModalDialog1(&quot;This is some news</tr></table> </body>
```

Here is source code of html page (cant see why it would not render correctly):

```
table += '<td>'+ '<a href="#" onclick="portal_openModalDialog1(&quot;'+oTitle+'&quot;)" >'+ 'click here' +'</a>'  + '</td>';
```

table += ''+ ''+ 'click here' +''  + '';

Comment: What is the content of `VarTest`? Where is `portal_openModalDialog` defined and what does it do? Define nothing happens; do you get console errors?

Comment: Post a complete code example please.

Comment: Hi I've got one vaeriable to pass (oTitle) but cannot pass two variables.. See updated question.

Answer (score 1):

The content of `onclick` attribute is parsed as JavaScript. You can just pass the variable, no magic involved:

```
<script>
    var myVar = 'foo';
    function myFunction(aVar) {
        alert('The variable: ' + aVar);
    }
</script>

<button onclick="myFunction(myVar)">Click me</button>
```

You can pass multiple variables, just make sure that the comma (`,`) is part of the resulting HTML and not a comma in the original JavaScript code:

```
<script>
    var myFirstVar = 'foo';
    var mySecondVar = 'bar';
    function myFunction(aVar, anotherVar) {
        alert('The first variable: ' + aVar + ', and the second: ' + anotherVar);
    }
</script>

<button onclick="myFunction(myFirstVar, mySecondVar)">Click me</button>
```

If you want to generate the button in the page, and you are sure your variables are meant to be strings, you can keep quoting the parameters:

```
document.write('<button onclick="myFunction(&quot;' + myFirstVar + '&quot;, &quot;' + mySecondVar + '&quot;)">Generated button 1</button>');
```

But, it is easier and less error prone to just pass the variables directly:

```
document.write('<button onclick="myFunction(myFirstVar, mySecondVar)">Generated button 2</button>');
```

Comment: @user32056, I've edited the answer to include functions with multiple parameters.